# How to create a stored procedure to assign age categories to a person age

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm doing an assignment for a class where I should determine if the person's age is between one of the following categories and insert the appropriate values:

```
0 – 12 – Child
13 – 19 – Teenager
20 + Adult.
```

I am aware that it is much easier to use a case option but it is required that I use if statements. I already have a table called marketing list where I altered and added the age and age category columns. Can anyone help me out please?

```
alter table marketing_list
    add age integer, 
        age_category varchar(20)

Create Procedure Age_Range
(
    @Id         integer,
    @Name       varchar(20),
    @DOB        date,
    @Parish     varchar(20),
    @Mobile     integer,
    @Mobile_Provider    varchar(7)
)
As
Begin
    update marketing_list 
    Set age = DATEDIFF(year, Date_of_Birth, GETDATE())

    If (DATEDIFF(year, @DOB,GETDATE()) > 0 and (DATEDIFF(year, @DOB, GETDATE()) <= 12))
    Begin
        update marketing_list 
        Set age_category = 'Child'
    End
End
```

Comment: `if` is not a function, it's a statement. If the requirement is to use `if`, then you would need to use a cursor to loop through the records and update them one at a time. (Unless of course you are allowed to create a function and put the if statements in that.)

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Comment: **Be careful**: the `DATEDIFF(Year, ...)` will look **only** at the year component of your date to calculate the difference. If you have `2014-12-31` and `2015-01-01`, the `DATEDIFF(year, )` will be **1** which is often not what you want! You might need to use either months or days to calculate an age more precisely

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle error in Scott's answer, which is otherwise correct in theory.  I would fix the error in place, but it is worth remarking on.  The problem is the lack of `else` for the first condition.  This means that when `@age` is less than 12, then the record will be updated twice.

Subtle bug.

So:

```
Create Procedure Age_Range (
    @Id         integer,
    @Name       varchar(20),
    @DOB        date,
    @Parish     varchar(20),
    @Mobile     integer,
    @Mobile_Provider    varchar(7)
) As
Begin
    declare @age int = datediff(YEAR, @dob, getdate());

    if(@age <= 12) 
    begin
        update marketing_list
            Set age_category = 'Child', age = @age
            where id = @id;
    end
    else if(@age > 12 AND @age <= 19)
    begin
        update marketing_list
            Set age_category = 'Teenager', age = @age
            where id = @id;
    end
    else begin
        update marketing_list
            Set age_category = 'Adult', age = @age
            where id = @id;
    end;    
end;
```

I also encourage you to:

- Use `begin`/`end` for all `if` statements.  It is easy to add a second statement by mistake, indent it, and *think* it is part of the `then` clause.
- Use semicolons to end statements.

Also, the use of `datediff(year, . . . )` to calculate age is merely an approximation.  This function counts the number of *year boundaries* between two dates (that is the number of ball drops in Times Square, for all practical purposes and modulo the timezone).

A more correct version would be:

```
Begin
    declare @age int = datediff(YEAR, @dob, getdate());

    if (dateadd(year, 12, dob) >= getdate())
    begin
        update marketing_list
            Set age_category = 'Child', age = @age
            where id = @id;
    end
    else if (dateadd(year, 20, dob) >= getdate()) 
    begin
        update marketing_list
            Set age_category = 'Teenager', age = @age
            where id = @id;
    end
    else begin
        update marketing_list
            Set age_category = 'Adult', age = @age
            where id = @id;
    end;    
end;
```

Comment: I noticed you have the where id statement..that means it would only update the table for a particular person..what if I wanted to update all at once?

Comment: In the real world you would simply run an update statement with a `CASE` statement. In the backwards world of academia where you must use `IF` you need to define a cursor or a loop and step through the rows. This is the least efficient way to do this operation.

Comment: Also your SP has a parameter `@id` and in the absence of any other info it is assumed this sp takes the IS and processes it

Answer (score 0):

Hi would something like this work? (psuedo code, but it should be fine)

```
Create Procedure Age_Range
(
    @Id         integer,
    @Name       varchar(20),
    @DOB        date,
    @Parish     varchar(20),
    @Mobile     integer,
    @Mobile_Provider    varchar(7)

)
As
Begin
    declare @age int
    set @age = datediff(YEAR, @dob, getutcdate())

    if(@age <= 12) 
        update marketing_list Set age_category = 'Child', age = @age where id = @id

    if(@age > 12 AND @age <= 19)
        update marketing_list Set age_category = 'Teenager', age = @age where id = @id
    else 
        update marketing_list Set age_category = 'Adult', age = @age where id = @id


end
```

Comment: thanks @scottsargent.. gonna test it to see if it works

Comment: As Gordon Linoff pointed out, I had a bug in my procedure.  Take a look at his answer, that fixes the bug.  Sorry about that!